# How to select last 4 data which start from second last row using sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table named `posts` with 3 columns which are `id`, `details`, `date` which contains the following data in ascending order:

```
+----+----------+-------+
| id | details  | date  |
+----+----------+-------+
|  1 | details1 | date1 |
|  2 | details2 | date2 |
|  3 | details3 | date3 |
|  4 | details4 | date4 |
+----+----------+-------+
```

I want to select data in descending order but I want to leave the first row details, like I want to leave row 4th id details, details4, date4, but then I want to select data from id 3 to 2 in, like `order by id desc limit 2` but leave the first row from last

Answer (score 2):

You can use the query with ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 1, n

That way, **n** is the amount of rows you want to fetch, and you're skipping the first row of the result by using **LIMIT 1,** .

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH a AS (
    SELECT 1 i
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 i
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 3 i
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 i
)
, b as (
    SELECT TOP 1 i FROM a ORDER BY i DESC
)
SELECT * 
FROM A 
EXCEPT 
SELECT * FROM B
ORDER BY i DESC
```

Comment: `TOP` is invalid MySQL syntax MySQL uses `LIMIT` instead.. `TOP` is SQL Server (MSSQL) syntax and MySQL also does not work with `EXCEPT`.. Besides `WITH AS` cte only works with MySQL 8.0+